# Turn '=IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH')' answer into numeric instead of text (to use autosum)

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I'm trying to get Excel to work out if a cell contains a certain courier company (DHL, DPD etc) and I want it to give out the number of miles to the nearest drop-off point. It works but it gives me a text answer instead of a number, this means autosum won't work. How do I change the code to give a numeric answer? Cheers Brian

```
    =IF(
        ISNUMBER(SEARCH("collect",Q2,1))=TRUE,"1", 
        IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("dhl",Q2,1))=TRUE,"2.6", 
        IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("DPD",Q2,1))=TRUE,"1", 
        IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("inpost",Q2,1))=TRUE,"1.2", 
        IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("hermes",Q2,1))=TRUE,"0.6",  
        IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("royal",Q2,1))=TRUE,"0.5", 
        IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("force",Q2,1))=TRUE,"0.5", 
        IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("ups",Q2,1))=TRUE,"0.6",  
        IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("yodel",Q2,1))=TRUE,"0", 
        IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("collection",Q2,1))=TRUE,"0",
    "No"))
```

Comment: just a quick note to say I've changed else "No" into 0 at the end

Comment: You can remove the quotes from numbers.

Comment: Also, `collection` will never be evaluated as `collect` will always come first.

Comment: hahaha, of course, lol, forgot about that, thank you

Comment: now where's the mark as answered

Comment: When you find yourself nesting `IF`s more than about three levels deep, there's usually a better solution. In this case, try putting the names of the couriers and their distances into a table and using `VLOOKUP` or `INDEX`/`MATCH`.

Comment: @jsheeran I'd suggest the same, but this situation in which you are checking if string begins with wouldn't support it.

Answer (score 0):

```
=IF
  (ISNUMBER(SEARCH("collection",Q2,0))=TRUE,1, 
  IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("dhl",Q2,1))=TRUE,2.6, 
  IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("DPD",Q2,1))=TRUE,1, 
  IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("inpost",Q2,1))=TRUE,1.2, 
  IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("hermes",Q2,1))=TRUE,0.6,  
  IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("royal",Q2,1))=TRUE,0.5, 
  IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("force",Q2,1))=TRUE,0.5, 
  IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("ups",Q2,1))=TRUE,0.6,  
  IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("yodel",Q2,1))=TRUE,0, 
0))))))))
```

Answer (score 0):

I just copied your formula in accordance with the comments, and removed `=TRUE`:

```
=IF
  (ISNUMBER(SEARCH("collection",Q2,1)),1, 
  IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("dhl",Q2,1)),2.6, 
  IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("DPD",Q2,1)),1, 
  IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("inpost",Q2,1)),1.2, 
  IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("hermes",Q2,1)),0.6,  
  IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("royal",Q2,1)),0.5, 
  IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("force",Q2,1)),0.5, 
  IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("ups",Q2,1)),0.6,  
  IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("yodel",Q2,1)),0, 
0))))))))
```

Answer (score 0):

If I followed your question correctly, this should work.
It has the advantage that you can extend the list easily to add other transporters and update distances.

[image]

You could use index() with match() in cell B3 instead of vlookup if you wish:

```
=IFERROR(INDEX($E$5:$E$13,MATCH(A3,$D$5:$D$13,0)),"not in list")
```

I used data validation to pick from the list in cell A3.